# Tensor flow 2.0 load save model without optimizer

Tags: tensorflow

I trained my model and save it like this:

```
    network.save(os.path.join(args.logdir, "cifar_model.h5") , 
    include_optimizer=False)
```

now, I would like to load it and continue training like this, but that doesn't work

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("...\\cifar_model.h5", compile ="False")



    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy")],
    )

    model.tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(args.logdir, update_freq=1000, profile_batch=1)
    model.tb_callback.on_train_end = lambda *_: None

    datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=15,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        horizontal_flip=True,
    )
    datagen.fit(cifar.train.data["images"])

    model.fit_generator(
        # cifar.train.data["images"], cifar.train.data["labels"],
        datagen.flow(cifar.train.data["images"], cifar.train.data["labels"], batch_size=args.batch_size),
        # batch_size=args.batch_size,
        steps_per_epoch=200,
        epochs=args.epochs,
        validation_data=(cifar.dev.data["images"], cifar.dev.data["labels"]),
        callbacks=[model.tb_callback],
    )
```

It throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Network' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

This should work according to https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing

Note that I'm saving without optimizer so I can avoid bug with loading optimizer.

UPDATE:
I found out how to do this when I know the exact structure of layers.
Which I know, then I can recreate model and use weights from a loaded model like this:

```
load = tf.keras.models.load_model("...\\cifar_model.h5", compile ="False")
model.set_weights(load.get_weights())
```

But I couldnt apply same for load.layers i think its possible if u dont have sequential layers

Comment: What happens if you try `compile=True`?

Comment: It's still same, I just add this parameter because I exported it without optimizer

Comment: Your code is 100% ok. How `network` is defined?